# No module named NaiveBayes

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, naivebayes

The code we are implementing is

```
from NaiveBayes import  Pool
import os

DClasses = ["python",  "java",  "hadoop",  "django",  "datascience",  "php"]

base = "learn/"
p = Pool()
for i in DClasses:
    p.learn(base + i, i)



base = "test/"
for i in DClasses:
    dir = os.listdir(base + i)
    for file in dir:
        res = p.Probability(base + i + "/" + file)
        print(i + ": " + file + ": " + str(res))
```

but we are getting error like no module found like naivebayes.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-30788f518a4c> in <module>()
----> 1 from NaiveBayes import  Pool
      2 import os
      3 
      4 DClasses = ["python",  "java",  "hadoop",  "django",  "datascience",  "php"]
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NaiveBayes'
```

Help to eradicate this error.Thanks.

Comment: Is this scikit-learn or what?

Comment: Have u installed NaiveBayes.? If not do `pip install NaiveBayes` in the command line

Comment: yes. It is scikit learn

Comment: Yeah i am using anaconda framework for scikit learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not seem to be from the [scikit-learn Naive Bayes algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.naive_bayes), which, in any case, do not have a `Pool` attribute or method.

It seems you are trying to use [another NaiveBayes library](https://github.com/yveskaufmann/Naive-Bayes), in which case your import should be

```
from NaiveBayes.Pool import Pool
```

as shown in the [example](https://github.com/yveskaufmann/Naive-Bayes/blob/master/main.py) there. But the message implies that you have not installed it; try from the shell

```
git clone https://github.com/yveskaufmann/Naive-Bayes
```

in your current directory (see also the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/) for cloning Github repos).

Comment: actually it has some code before it. I did that in scikit learn. The code which i have posted is extension to that code.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NaiveBayes.Pool'; 'NaiveBayes' is not a package` I am getting this.

Comment: the code i posted above has some code before. I implemented that code in scikit learn. The code which i posted is extension to that.

Comment: @MurthyRouthula Where did you get the posted code from? Clearly you have *not* installed the library I have linked to, but it certainly seems you are trying to use *that* one (other implementations do not use `pool`)...

Comment: can you help me how to install that library through conda install?

Comment: @MurthyRouthula I highly doubt it is available in conda or pip - it is a project abandoned for at least 3 years, with 0 Github stars (i.e. nobody seems to be using it or found it useful)...

Comment: yeah it is there in pip. I too didnt find it in conda. Thanks.

Comment: @MurthyRouthula if you mean [this](https://pypi.org/project/NaiveBayes/), it is a **different** project, and I guess it will not resolve your issue (again, no `Pool` method here)...

Comment: yeah. I understand. can you please provide me the link of some information about the project NaiveBayes.pool library what we are discussing?

Comment: @MurthyRouthula I have included links in my post - I think that's everything there is. Kindly *accept* the answer, will you?

Comment: Yeah, the library what we are discussing about is right. But I am not getting how to get that.

Comment: @MurthyRouthula see updated answer (and upvotes are most welcome).

Comment: @MurthyRouthula any reason you *un*accepted the answer?

Comment: yeah I imported the module that you have posted. even though there is a learn() function in Pool.py , I am getting Error like `AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'learn'`

Comment: @MurthyRouthula this is reason to open a *different* question (with the new details), not to unaccept the answer to this one, which was about a *different* error (which you *don't get now*)!!! You are very welcome... :(