# Unable to get the method 'learn' from Pool.py

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am implementing the code

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/stepfourward/naivebayes/Naive-Bayes/')
from NaiveBayes import *
import os

DClasses = ["python",  "java",  "hadoop",  "django",  "datascience",  "php"]

base = "learn/"
p = Pool()
for i in DClasses:
    p.learn(base + i, i)
```

[NaiveBayes](https://github.com/yveskaufmann/Naive-Bayes) module contains `Pool.py` that has the function `learn()`:

```
def learn(self, directory, dclass_name):
        """
        directory is a path, where the files of the class with the name dclass_name can be found
        """
        x = DocumentClass(self.__vocabulary)
        dir = os.listdir(directory)
        for file in dir:
            d = Document(self.__vocabulary)
            print(directory + "/" + file)
            d.read_document(directory + "/" + file, learn=True)
            x = x + d
        self.__document_classes[dclass_name] = x
        x.SetNumberOfDocs(len(dir))
```

but when I am applying the method `p.learn(base + i, i)` metioned in code above I am getting attribute error.

```
AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'learn'
```

How to eradicate this error. Thanks.

Comment: What is the `NaiveBayes ` package?

Comment: Did you try `from NaiveBayes.Pool import Pool`, as suggested in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078969/no-module-named-naivebayes/52079151#52079151)?

Comment: For reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079151/4819449 -- the issue is that you want `NaiveBayes.Pool.Pool` but you have `NaiveBayes.Pool` -- just use the `sklearn` one anyway -- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html

Comment: we are not getting method from module. we able to import that module. @desertnaut

Comment: @FHTMitchell That is Package programmed and taken by us for our use case

Comment: If the answer was helpful, kindly accept it, otherwise please leave feedback...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the correct steps to use the said NaiveBayes library, after you have cloned the repo as explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078969/no-module-named-naivebayes/52079151#52079151) in a folder `Naive-Bayes`:

What you do

```
import sys
sys.path.append('Naive-Bayes/')  # your own path here
from NaiveBayes import *         # NO error here

p = Pool()
```

produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Pool' is not defined
```

What you should do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('Naive-Bayes/')
from NaiveBayes.Pool import Pool # correct import

p = Pool()  # runs OK now

DClasses = ["python",  "java",  "hadoop",  "django",  "datascience",  "php"]

base = "learn/"

for i in DClasses:
    p.learn(base + i, i)
```

At *this* point (but not before), I am getting an *expected* error, simply because your directories (e.g. `learn/python`) are not present in my machine:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/herc/SO/Naive-Bayes/NaiveBayes/Pool.py", line 29, in learn
    dir = os.listdir(directory)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'learn/python'
```

but the clear message is that the `Pool` object and the `learn` method in `Pool.py` can indeed be accessed.

Tested with Python 3.4.3 in Ubuntu...

Comment: It is also not working. getting error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NaiveBayes.Pool'; 'NaiveBayes' is not a package`

Comment: @MurthyRouthula probably you have messed something up in cloning the repo (or the path), since it works OK here